# how create a sub site in Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am working on classified ads website using **mvc3** there are some requirements that **Client(User)** 
 can create its own **page** it might be **sub site** where User can place its own **ads** 
 so every **sub site (page)** have its own **database** that will be create **dynamically** Html,style etc. 
 i am using **(LINQ EntityFrameWork)**
 I have no idea how to do this.. **i need help.**...?

Comment: Is there really a requirement to have a seperate database for each page?  If not, since you will have many 'pages', you could create a Page model and have a Pages controller.  As long as you have all your necessary properties defined in the model, then the standard REST methods that the controller generates for you should get you going.

Comment: can you provide me any example or sample that guide me please

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't have any experience with asp.net mvc 3 yet.  If this is the case, than I would suggest Scott Guthries site: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx.  And getting started with mvc at the asp.net site:  http://www.asp.net/mvc.

Comment: i think you can't get my question on user can add its own categories for ads like Electronic (sub category mobile,computer )so every user have its own categories how i manage this and on this page there are some utilities that can change by user..( i think small content management solution)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to first figure out how to approach this requirement...however here is a post that may/could be helpful to you...this post uses VB.NET and ASP.NET but the thing you need to look at is the approach...you could use it if you like it...
[Creating an ASP.NET Dynamic Data Web Site with VB.Net](http://dotnetstories.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/creating-an-asp-net-dynamic-data-web-site-with-vb-net/)

Comment: i want to build a basic content management system (like Joomla)